# How to deploy angular / .net7 web app without Azure, etc

Tags: deployment, virtual-machine, vps, .net-7.0

I have Angular 16.2.3 and .net7 web application and MSSQL Server Database, everything works perfect locally i.e. on localhost.

Web application created using command `dotnet new angular` from terminal.

I have a VPS (Virtual Private Server) and want to deploy my application there.

My main point is not to use Azure or any other similar provider and configure/run server to deploy website/API/ Database myself.

Also I understand that regarding Database it might whole another story so would love to know about that as well.

Would be grateful to get any instructions how can I do it properly and secure. Will purchase any other necessary tools to do it properly (i.e. another VPS for Database , Virtual Machine).

If provided information is not enough please let me know and I will provide more regarding application itself or tools used etc..

Haven't tried anything myself yet. Looked up some information online and found some solutions using Kestrel and Docker but would love to have proper explanation.